# ¿Cómo se compara un string con un char?

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo C que compara los char de punctuacion para calcular cuantos frases tenemos:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int nb_de_lettres;
    int nbre_de_mots;
    int nbre_de_phrase;
    string phrase;
    int i = 0;

    phrase = get_string ("what's your text?\n ");

    // compter les phrases
    while (phrase[i]!='\0')
    {
        if ((phrase[i]=="!")||(phrase[i]==".")||(phrase[i]=="?"))
        {
            nbre_de_phrase=nbre_de_phrase+1;
        }
    i++;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo me devuelve el programa que:

```
$ make readability_hugues 
readability_hugues.c:31:23: error: result of comparison against a string literal is unspecified (use an explicit string comparison function instead) [-Werror,-Wstring-compare]
        if ((phrase[i]=="!")||(phrase[i]==".")||(phrase[i]=="?"))
                      ^ ~~~
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated.
make: *** [<builtin>: readability_hugues] Error 1
```

No entiendo el error porque lo hizo de una otra manera y funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    int letterscount = 0;
    int wordcount = 1;
    int sentencecount = 0;

//count words
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    {
       if ((text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') || (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'))
       {
           letterscount++;
       }
       else if (text[i] == ' ')
       {
           wordcount++;
       }
       else if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?')
       {
           sentencecount++;
       }
    }
//    printf("letters: %i; words: %i; sentences: %i\n", letterscount, wordcount, sentencecount);


}
```

Y funcion a bien. La differencia parecia ser en lors argumentos del main. Lo hizo sin estos y tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo se compara un `string` con un `char`?

No se compara.

---

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) un `string` es una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres, mientras que un `char` es un un sólo caracter; en otras palabras estás preguntando ¿Cómo se compara `Albaricoque` con `n`? que es una comparación sin sentido.

Lo que quieres comparar son dos `string` y para eso existe la función [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) (*`str`ing `c`o`mp`are*). Esa función compara dos cadenas y devuelve los siguientes valores:

- -1 La primera cadena es menor a la segunda.

- 0 Ambas cadenas son iguales.

- 1 La primera cadena es mayor a la segunda.

Por lo tanto, probablemente quieras hacer esto (suponiendo que `phrase` sea una formación de caracteres):

```
if (!strcmp(phrase, "!") || !strcmp(phrase, ".") || !strcmp(phrase, "?"))
{
    nbre_de_phrase=nbre_de_phrase+1;
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Muchas gracias PaperMindMaster ! Tambien lo hice con `if (phrase[i] == '.' || phrase [i] =='!' || phrase[i] == '?')` y funciona

Comment: Claro, porque asumiendo que `phrase` es de tipo `char *`, entonces `phrase[numero]` es de tipo `char` y cualquier cáracter entre comillas simples es `char` ergo: comparas los mismos tipos.